Bash: Conditional formatting against an array with printf
In a bash script, I have some dynamic entries in an array that assemble together at one point for readable output with printf. I'd like to save the cursor at some point while printing through the array though, to go back to that point and clear everything from there until the end of the line. This should all happen dynamically.
This is what I have, to illustrate what's going on:
#!/bin/bash

foo=1 

parts=(
  "one"
  "two"
  "three"
  "four"
)

[[ ${foo} -eq 1 ]] && parts+=("five")

# build the line of parts and save the cursor with ANSI escape '\033[s' before a specific part
# in this case, before the last part
printf '\r%s %s %s %s \033[s%s ' "${parts[0]}" "${parts[1]}" "${parts[2]}" "${parts[3]}" "${parts[4]}"
sleep 1
# restore cursor to saved position and clear everything until end of line
printf '\033[u\033[0K\n'

This shows:
one two three four

after 1 second, which is exactly what I want. The sleep is added in order to see before/after the line clearing.
Reading other answers, I've seen one can concatenate the array passed to printf with "${parts[*]}", which would be preferred here, to avoid assembling the line by a loop or doing it manually, like as in the above example. But! Is it possible to tell printf to do some specific formatting at a specific point in the array?
For example, how do I tell printf to save the cursor before expanding the last part of the array, for instance, like in the example above?
i.e.
printf '\r%s ' "${parts[*]}"
#         ^ How to insert specific formatting for last array part here?


So why not just write a loop?

Only a hint: You can use (( foo == 1 )) or more compact ((foo==1)) instead of [[ ${foo} -eq 1 ]]

FYI whenever you talk about "cursor" in a question it makes us think you want to interact with your terminal in some way to manipulate the position of the cursor and so some people who don't know/care about terminal manipulation will immediately move on to the next question. If instead you just want to do normal text manipulation by saving some index in an array or character position in a string then use those terms instead of "cursor" to avoid any confusion and keep more people interested in your question.

IIRC In your previous questions you talked about "cursor" too but then accepted an answer that was just simple text manipulation so even if in the real world you do want to do something with the cursor but that's not important to the problem you're trying to solve, then create and post a [mcve] about your actual text manipulation problem without talking about moving the cursor around. In this question, for example, you seem to be interested in formatting different parts of an array - that has nothing to do with where the cursor is in your terminal so don't bring that up.

Not sure what you're talking about. This is a minimal reproducible example, and the OP literally deals with \033[s and \033[u to manipulate the cursor.


Is it possible to tell printf to do some specific formatting at a specific point in the array?

No. But in this case, assuming there are at least two elements in parts, you can do:
printf '\r%s \e[s%s' "${parts[*]::${#parts[@]}-1}" "${parts[-1]}"


You can't "tell printf to do some specific formatting at a specific point in the array" because its argument (when using "${parts[*]}") is the already concatenated array. But you can accordingly modify the array before passing it to printf. Use a copy of that array if you still need the original state.
# make a copy if needed, and modify the array at a given position
pos=2

# - either by modifying the item itself
#displayparts=("${parts[@]}")
#displayparts[$pos]="$(printf '\033[s%s' "${displayparts[$pos]}")"

# - or by inserting another item (beware: ths creates another space when concatenating)
#displayparts=("${parts[@]::$pos}" "$(printf '\033[s')" "${parts[@]:$pos}")

# - or by combining both approaches into one (no abundant space)
displayparts=("${parts[@]::$pos}" "$(printf '\033[s')${parts[@]:$pos}")

# display the modified array
printf '\r%s ' "${displayparts[*]}"
sleep 1
printf '\033[u\033[0K\n'

